# Emails being received with winmail.dat even when sent as plaintext

Tags: email, ms-office

My colleague is sending emails with Microsoft Excel 2016 attachments, from Microsoft Outlook 2016, to a business partner who uses a Mac (I am not sure what version of OS)

He has tried sending as html, rich text, and plain text and in every case, the recipient receives the email with a winmail.dat attachment instead of the excel attachment.    We have proved that he is correctly sending the emails in each format by sending them to me in those formats.

I have googled this, but every article suggests sending as plain text is the solution.  But sending as plain text isn't working.

Is there some other trick to getting emails sent from Outlook 2016 to be received properly by Apple Mac owners?

Comment: Try archiving the file(s) before attaching as a .zip archive.  Also see if the winmail.dat file can be opened using [http://www.winmaildat.com](http://www.winmaildat.com).

Comment: It probably can,  but the guy we're sending the files to is not very technical, and my colleague is regularly sending files, it gets a bit impractical to keep converting.   I've suggested archiving, or saving as an older verson of excel, or as a pdf.  I'll update the question when I hear back.

Comment: If it is an Exchange server contact the mail admin, that option can be turned off at the back end.